# React redux logic done in parent reducer vs. child reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In the react redux doc todo example, Dan passes the action with type `TOGGLE_TODO` to the `todos` which then passes it on to each individual todo. I notice that his logic was checking for the `todo.id` was in the `todo` reducer. Couldn't this logic have been done in the `todos` as well? To me, it would seem better to take care of the logic at a higher level as your iterating through each todo rather than passing the work to every todo and having them figure out if they need to toggle or now. Is there a reason why Dan did it this way?

```
const todo = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return {
        id: action.id,
        text: action.text,
        completed: false
      }
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      if (state.id !== action.id) {
        return state
      }

      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        completed: !state.completed
      })

    default:
      return state
  }
}

const todos = (state = [], action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'ADD_TODO':
      return [
        ...state,
        todo(undefined, action)
      ]
    case 'TOGGLE_TODO':
      return state.map(t =>
        todo(t, action)
      )
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export default todos
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are right, if you take a look at [todomvc example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/examples/todomvc/reducers/todos.js) from redux source code repository, you'll see only one `todos` reducer.

The docs may be a bit outdated or such nested reducers may be just an example of its possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

It's just one possible approach to structuring the reducer logic.  In this case, it looks like Dan chose to define a function to handle the case of updating a single todo, and was then able to reuse that function for multiple cases by using it within higher-level iteration logic.